# Drupal Site Map Module

Tags: drupal

I am looking for a module that can create sitemap in Drupal, but couldn't find any. I tried [Site Map](http://drupal.org/project/site_map) module, but it can only generate a sitemap page; it can't create a sitemap block at the end of every page. I also tried [site menu module](http://drupal.org/project/sitemenu), but it can't create a sitemap block as shown above, as well.

Maybe it's just that I don't know how to configure, but I read every readme file, and tried for a few days, still can't get it to work.

Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the same problem, after trying a module (site-map) but missing customization options I wrote a custom module. Took less time then messing with the site-map module, for just getting a site map the following code is enough (adapt your-menu):

```
function sitemap_render_menu ($menu) {
    $output = "<ul>";
    foreach ($menu as $item) {
    $link = $item["link"];
    if ($link["hidden"]) {
        continue;
    }

    $output .= "<li><a href=\"" . check_url(url($link["href"], $link["options"])) . "\">" . $link["title"] . "</a></li>";

    if ($item["below"]) {
        $output .= sitemap_render_menu($item["below"]);
    }
    }

    $output .= "</ul>";
    return $output;
}

function sitemap_content () {
    $output = "<h1>Sitemap</h1>";
    $output .= "<span id=\"sitemap\">";
    $output .= sitemap_render_menu(menu_tree_all_data("your-menu"));
    $output .= "</span>";
    return $output;
}


function sitemap_menu () {
    $items = array();

    $items["sitemap"] = array (
        "title" => "Sitemap",
        "page callback" => "sitemap_content",
        "access arguments" => array("access content"),
        "type" => MENU_CALLBACK);

    return $items;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There is a basic comparison of sitemap modules at http://groups.drupal.org/node/15980

I have used sitemenu and it worked for my needs, but the real answer depends on how you structure your site with taxonomy, content types, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Something like [Auto Menu](http://drupal.org/project/automenu) might work for you here as well.  You could simply add the menu it generates to a footer block on your front page.

Comment: Unfortunately Auto Menu is not available for Drupal 6 :(

Answer (score 1):

With the Site Map module installed, this php code will print the site map.

```
<?php echo theme('site_map'); ?>
```

You could create an empty views block and specify the above for the empty text, selecting the PHP Code input format.

There may be a better way to create a custom block to display php code, but I don't know it.

Answer (score 0):

My idea here is to use [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module with customized block type.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can benefit from [Menu block](http://drupal.org/project/menu_block) module. as you can create menu blocks for all the menus you need in the footer. Then you can add them all in footer or in a one block using minipanels block (from [panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) module).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Footer_sitemap module which provides us with the configurable block.
https://drupal.org/project/footer_sitemap

Answer (score 0):

This is a little mod of best answer it uses current theme to show hierarchy

```
function sitemap_render_menu ($menu) {

    $output = "<ul  class='menu'>";

    foreach ($menu as $item) {
        $link = $item["link"];
        if ($link["hidden"]) {
            continue;
        }

        $cc=($item["below"]) ? "class='collapsed'" : '';

        $output .= "<li $cc><a href=\"" . check_url(url($link["href"], $link["options"])) . "\">" . $link["title"] . "</a>";

        if ($item["below"]) {
            $output .= sitemap_render_menu($item["below"]);
        }

        $output .= "</li>";

    }

    $output .= "</ul>";
    return $output;
}

function sitemap_content ($title,$menu) {
    $output = "<h1>$title</h1>";
    $output .= "<span id=\"sitemap\">";
    $output .= sitemap_render_menu(menu_tree_all_data($menu));
    $output .= "</span>";
    return $output;
}


function sitemap_menu () {
    $items = array();

    $items["sitemap"] = array (
      "title" => "Sitemap",
      "page callback" => "sitemap_content",
      "access arguments" => array("access content"),
      "type" => MENU_CALLBACK);

    return $items;
}

print sitemap_content("Navigational menu","Navigation");
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution which doesn't depend on content being included as a menu item can be achieved by :

Creating a new view

Output as a block

Using Fields:

Content Title (configured to "Link this field to the original piece of content"

Content Type (configured to "Exclude from display")

Format as

Unformatted list with settings - Grouping field Nr.1 select Content:Type;

Filter Criterea:
Content: Published (Yes)
Content Type - Configure to select the content types you wish to include;

Sort criteria - Configure as per your preference